# Combination of LuaLaTeX and TikZ lead to lots of undefined control sequence errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I have a document that compiles fine under LuaLaTeX, until I add to the preamble the line: `\usepackage{tikz}`. Compiling after adding that line yields a lot of errors like this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pdf@escapestring ...capestring("\luaescapestring 
                                                 {#1}", "byte")}
l.1 ...K [1][-]{section.1}{Probabilities et al.}{}
                                                 % 1
```

Now, as far as I can tell, the document (which at this point has no TikZ code proper, just the use package line) compiles as fine as before. If I add TikZ images, it still seems to compile properly... but then why are those errors being generated? I doesn't seem like a wise strategy to just ignore them...

I tried using `\usepackage{tikz,pgf}`, and in reverse, but to no avail.

Can anyone help? I just pasted the first error, because they all look fairly similar (to me at least...). Just for the kicks, here's the *last* one:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pdf@filesize ...xcmds.filesize("\luaescapestring 
                                                 {#1}")}
l.346 \end{document}

)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: cretae a _complete_ example which shows the error. However, try before loading `tikz` `\usepackage{luacode}`

Comment: On my system `\luaescapestring` is defined by the pdftexcmds package (loaded by tikz) from Heiko Oberdiek. Perhaps your version is outdated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's precisely right! I'm embarrassed to admit that I had, long ago, replicated in my home folder the tex hierarchy, and placed in there an aeons old version of that package. And then I completely forgot about it!! Removing it and rerunning texhash solved the problem! Thank you very much for the hint!